# Cannibalizing a printer, how to figure out what some of the parts are/do

Tags: motor, datasheet, brushless-dc-motor

My son an I are attempting to cannibalize a printer a HP LaserJet 1300.  It used to work and print, but it was low on toner and the company we got it from replaced it instead of buying new toner.

So, we have some parts and are trying to build a centrifuge (the low tech version) using the motor inside the printer.  It is a Nidec RK2-0063 45M0600024 24VDC 1.4A.  You can see what it looks like here: http://www.kpsurplus.com/hp-printer-nidec-rk2-0063-main-motor-45m0600024-24v1-4a.html

Anyway, we have been drawing a blank on finding a datasheet for this motor/control assembly.  The 5 pin connector has a pinout of Vcc FG /DEC /ACC GND but we don't know what FG means, and don't know what to feed it on /ACC and /DEC

Vcc -> Gnd is ~24 VDC which is to be expected since it is a 24 volt motor, but what are the other pins for/what voltages should we use to control the motor.

What kind of motor would you call this?

Comment: "Cannibalizing"...hmmm. Nice!

Comment: [This vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ2V2hJ84gk) seems to have better info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a "Brushless DC Motor" (BLDCM or BLDC motor).

If so it will have a controller on board.

The following is experienced based guesswork

- /ACC = accelerate motor when grounded (/ indicating low)
- / DEC = decelerate motor when grounded.
- Vcc is **probably** 24V but just may be eg 5V.
- Gnd - something has to be easy ;-) = ground.

/ FG **may** be "frame ground". But maybe not.

I'd be tempted to find old printers in a dumpster and tear them apart rather than buy one like this BUT it does seem to be a very capable motor from the rating plate. Have you asked the supplier of they have a basic data sheet - you'd hope they would have when selling something like this.

**TRY**

- Connect ground to ground. So far so good.
- Connect 12V or so to Vcc via a 100 R ( = 100 ohm) resistor.
- Ground /ACC via a 1k or so resistor.

IF the motor responds go from there.

If not,try 24 V, but I'd be mildly nervous.

Once/if it shows signs of rotating (even a kick) you can try removing the 100 R resistor.

FG **may** need to be grounded.

If there is an onboard IC it may give some clues.

Report.

Comment: Well, we are using 24V because we are using the power supply from the printer (we haven't de-soldered any of the main board yet).  We shorted /ACC to ground and it took right off, gets a pretty good bit of speed too.  BTW we didn't buy this, it was a cast off we got for free,

Comment: Nidec appears to have many brands and I couldn't even find mention of this motor on their websites.

Comment: /DEC appears to do nothing @ the moment, once we get this hacked a little more, we'll try to figure that one out.

Comment: OK - that information would have been useful "up front". So /ACC is apparently "accelerate". So /DEC is almost certainly "brake". Try /ACC from rest for say 1 second, then time time taken to coast to rest. Repeat but once /ACC is o/c ground /DEC and see if it stops faster. The brave can ground /ACC, wait 1 second and then ground /DEC with /ACC still grounded :-). Report.

Comment: I have a similar motor and the FG pin appears to be connected to the FGSOUT pin: http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/motor/brushless/bd6761fs-e.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I found the same motor in a laser printer and I tried to connect this way:

- VCC -> 12v from PC power supply (I don't have any 24v source)
- GND -> ground
- ACC -> connected to VCC with a 10k pull-up resistor
- DEC -> connected    to VCC with a 10k pull-up resistor
- then I connected one button to ACC and one to DEC both going to ground.

The result is that when I push one button the motor starts and when I pushed the other one the motor stops.

Next step is to wonder if there is a way to control the speed; the pins are called ACC and DEC, not START and STOP, so it might be possible to do something with PWM.

From my experience FG is a square wave indicating the frequency the motor coils are working at; and usually with some calculation is possible to retrieve the RPM. Anyway I need to connect to an Arduino to try both PWM and reading FG.

Answer (score 0):

FG stands for Fixed Gain. It needs for smooth rotation.